# Removing quotes from each string in an array - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've searched here: http://w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp but could not find any convenience method to perform this function. If I have an array `var arrayOfStrings = ["20","10","30","100"]`, is there a quick way to remove all quotes (") from each string in this array without having to loop through?

I essentially want to create this: `var arrayOfNumbers = [20,10,30,100]`

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to convert your strings into integers ?

Comment: @BaliBalo edited to be more clear. thanks

Comment: Use MDN docs, w3c is aweful: http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want number conversion, you can do it like this...

```
var arrayOfNumbers = arrayOfStrings.map(Number);
```

The `.map()` method creates a new array populated with the return value of the function you provide.

Since the built-in `Number` function takes the first argument given and converts it to a primitive number, it's very usable as the callback for `.map()`. Note that it will interpret hexadecimal notation as a valid number.

---

Another built-in function that would accomplish the same thing as the callback is `parseFloat`.

```
var arrayOfNumbers = arrayOfStrings.map(parseFloat)
```

The `parseInt` function however will not work since `.map()` also passes the current *index* of each member to the callback, and `parseInt` will try to use that number as the *radix* parameter.

---

- [MDN Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) *(includes compatibility patch)*

---

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/UDWvH/

```
[
    20,
    10,
    30,
    100
]
```

Comment: The same thing how i do it for string

Comment: what if I have array like this `["d:3", "v:5"]` how to convert to key value ?

Answer (score 4):

You could try like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
{
    myArray[i] = parseInt(myArray[i], 10);
}
```

Have a look to the [parseInt function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: +1 for a good answer, -1 for not putting `{` and `}` around your loop body.

Comment: pass `10` for radix to parseInt!

Comment: @jbabey: A one-statement loop body does not need braces.

Comment: @Bergi that doesn't stop it from being a bad practice.

Comment: @jbabey: It's not a bad practice, as long as you surround it with other good practices, like proper indentation.

Comment: @amnotiam http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/16528/single-statement-if-block-braces-or-no

Comment: @jbabey: Yeah? What's your point? It's not a bad practice as long as you surround it with good practices. Just because some coders can be sloppy, doesn't make it "bad". I exclude curly braces when possible and sensible, and I don't have issues with it. I also omit semicolons when possible and sensible, and again, no issues. As a result, my code is very clean and readable.

Comment: @amnotiam then we have different opinions on what "clean and readable" means - to each his own :)

Comment: @jbabey: Yes, it's nice that we can pick and choose for ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

For browsers that support [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
var arr = ["20","10","30","100"];
var newArr = JSON.parse("[" + arr.join() + "]");
console.log(typeof arr[0]);  //string
console.log(typeof newArr[0]);  //number
```

Answer (score -3):

You do not need to do anything, the double quotes in JavaScript are identifiers that state that the data within them is a string. This means they are not part of the array or data itself.

You can loop using a standard For loop.